# Any simple music app for an iphone 5s on iOS 11?

Tags: iphone-app, audio-player

I need a simple audio player for my iPhone 5s (iOS 11), just play some voice recordings I upload to iCloud. It seems like most apps in the app store won't work due to the age of the iPhone/iOS.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you try VLC https://apps.apple.com/us/app/vlc-for-mobile/id650377962

Comment: VLC worked fine. I tried another 4 before and none worked, even though some said iOS11 compatible.  I didn't try VLC before as I thought it was intended for video and would be heavy.  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. If you are happy with my andwer feel free to upvote and/or accept is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [VLC Player](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/vlc-for-mobile/id650377962). It seems to run on version 9.0 of iOS. And this software can offer you a lot of options to play audio and video. It is not perfect (for me), some controls behave differently but it is OK.